# JS: EcmaScript6 how to pass different number of parameters to extended class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having a little problem with my class. It got to be something very easy, but I just cant find out the solution. Class `Cuboid` works well, but the class `Cube` is just not okey, I think I've used the `super` method in a wrong way.

Just give me a little hint. Thank you in advance.

```js
class Cuboid {
  constructor(length, width, height) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }
  get surfaceArea() {
    return (this.length * this.width + this.length * this.height + this.height * this.width) * 2;
  }
  get volume() {
    return this.length * this.width * this.height;
  }
}
class Cube extends Cuboid {
  constructor(length) {
    super(length);
    this.height = length;
  }
}
```

Guys, why do you downvote my question? It's not really nice...

Comment: The superclass constructor takes arguments length, width, and height, not just length.

Comment: What do you mean by "is just not okey"?

Comment: You probably want to pass the 3 correct parameters to `super()`, and remove the `this.height = length;` part.

Comment: Use super(length, length, length) in Cube.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Class `Cube` have to make a cube from `Cuboid` class. Everybody knows how the cube looks like, to count the volume and area, you need only one parameter, like length.

Comment: @Nosyara Thank you. Damn, I knew it has to be something trivial. Please make a full answer, I will mark it as the best one.

Comment: @Patrickkx My point was, it's an entirely useless problem statement, which is why I downvoted your question. I could say my car "is just not okey", which could mean that there's a bit of dust on the rear view mirror. It could also mean the engine is on fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I suggesting Cube is Cuboid with all 3 dimension equal. So there is 2 options to do it:

1.

```
class Cube extends Cuboid {
  constructor(length) {
    super(length, length, length);
  }
}
```

2.

```
class Cuboid {
  constructor(length, width, height) {
    this.length = length || 0;
    this.width = width || this.length;
    this.height = height || this.width;
  }
  // ....
```

Comment: By the way, if you would upvote my question I would be grateful, coz stackoverflow blocked my ability to ask further question because of 3x downvote.

Comment: Edit your question in a way it will be useful for other users. Like: how to pass different number of parameters to extended class.

Comment: The second one is a pretty horrible idea, it doesn't work when you pass `0`. If at all, use parameter defaults: `constructor(length, width = length, height = length) { … }`

Comment: I know, it is just a direction to way you can handle such things